# Sending 2 Object Model as an input to @body retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Hi I want to send 2 Object WITHOUT creating new api model.

For Example, I have a class with name User And another with name Device.

I want to combine both of these models and send it as a request body.

Retrofit Post request will be something below:

```
@POST("/login")
fun loginAPI(@Body user: UserModel, @Body device : DeviceModel): Observer<CallbackModel>
```

As well Final JSON Will be something like this:

```
"user" : {
   "username" : "XXX"
   ...
}
"device" : {
   "imei" : "XXX"
   ...
}
```

**Remember:** I know that I can create a new Class that contains user and device attributes and etc. The problem is that I don't like to create a new class for each endpoint.

Comment: can you modify your endpoint? if is yes, you can mix all of this in a single json

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit doesn't allow multiple body objects to be sent in a single request since it contains the message body of a POST request. Therefore as an alternative solution, you can pass both of your model in a hashmap body as follows:

**API Interface**

```
@POST("/login")
fun loginAPI(@Body map: HashMap): Observer<CallbackModel>
```

**Calling class**

```
val map = HashMap<String, Object>()
map.put("user", userModel)
map.put("device", deviceModel)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your object like below:

```
JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();

JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
user.put("key", "value");
...

JSONObject device = new JSONObject();
device.put("key", "value");
...

parent.put("user", user);
parent.put("device", device);
```

Comment: I don't want to pass JSONObject, indeed I want to pass both User and Device Model as an input of Retrofit post request inteface

Comment: @SinaMirshafiei have 2 suggestions for you: 1) send user and device Query parameters so you don't need to create and send any json object. 2) if you want to send your data as body you have to combine them in one json because Body here means message Body of HTML POST and you can only pass one parameter as Body.